# Why is my list extraction to a data frame resulting in fewer values than the list contains?

Tags: r, list

I have a list of around 200,000 elements.

Each element stores two values and represents map coordinates (latitude and longitude).

I want to extract the values into `lat` and `lon` variables and so far have come up with this:

```
for(i in nrow(users)) {
  lat[i] <- users$location[[i]][1]
  lon[i] <- users$location[[i]][2]
}

coords <- as.data.frame(cbind(lat, lon))
```

As far as I can see, it appears to have extracted the first element and then 19 elements at the end with nothing between (20 in total when checking with `complete.cases`).

Ideally, I would like to exclude `NA` and `0, 0` values also.

Looking at the list directly, I can see that this is wrong as there are several values contained within it.

If I compare the final data frame to the list items, the figures don't match.  For example, the value `-73.9924` exists in the list but not in my data frame.

Where am I going wrong?

**My final data frame:**

```
> coords[complete.cases(coords), ]
            lat       lon
1       37.4590 -122.1781
96960   40.8152  -73.3624
96961   40.0409  -75.6374
96962   42.5153  -70.9075
96963   33.7773  -84.3366
96964   39.9831  -86.2876
96965   40.7588  -73.9680
96966   36.7646  -76.1990
96967   44.7415  -91.3012
96968   42.6179  -70.7154
96969   40.5953  -74.6173
96970   50.8000   -0.3667
96971   34.0523 -118.3852
96972   41.4468  -74.0689
96973   26.9467  -80.2170
96974   40.7139  -74.0079
96975   34.2313 -118.1486
96976   43.6655  -79.4378
96977   39.0972  -84.1225
96978 -122.1781   37.4590
```

**Sample of list contents:**

```
[[734]]
[1] 0 0

[[735]]
[1] 0 0

[[736]]
[1] 0 0

[[737]]
[1] 0 0

[[738]]
[1] -73.9924  40.7553

[[739]]
[1] 0 0

[[740]]
[1] -76.7818  39.4370

[[741]]
[1] -97.822  37.751

[[742]]
NULL

[[743]]
[1] 0 0

[[744]]
[1] 0 0
```

Comment: Please reduce your problem to a minimal reproducible problem. And you might even find your solution on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `for` loop. Use `sapply` with `[` as the function:

```
lat<-sapply(users$location,"[",1)
lon<-sapply(users$location,"[",2)
```

Not sure what's the cause of the skipping of lines, but if this still doesn't work, we can work through the root cause from there.

If you want to avoid `NULL`s use this with the two vectors you created:

```
lat<-unlist(lat[!sapply(lat,is.null)])
```

and similarly for lon.
Alternatively, you can apply the same logic to users$location before creating lat and lon - may be faster with long lists.

If you want everything in one (somewhat) elegant command, I would suggest going through the intervening process of turning the list into a matrix using `sapply`, and then changing it into a data.frame:

```
coords<-as.data.frame(t(sapply(users$location[!sapply(users$location,is.null)],"[",c(1,2)))) %>% 
dplyr::rename(lat=V1,lon=V2) %>% 
dplyr::filter(!lat==0,!lon==0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but I tried your approach and it seems to have worked perfectly.  It also includes `NULL` and `0` values (which is what I expected) - is there a way to remove these upon generation?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Hmm... Gawd I hate working with lists... See edited answer above.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you!  Is there a way to remove `0`-values, also?

Comment: These would extract the zeroes only, right?  Also, I changed this slightly as it was missing the `row`/`column` separator: `coords[coords$lat == 0 & coords$lon == 0, ]`. Is there a way to remove the zeroes on the fly?  The actual zero values are `0.0000`.

Comment: right, sorry, forgot the `!`s. before the conditions. Should be: `coords<-coords[!coords$lat==0 & !coords$lon==0,]` or `dplyr::filter(coords, !lat==0, !lon==0)`.

Comment: Ah yes, perfect thank you! Chosen as the solution and duly upvoted for your efforts!  I suggest you add the extra code to the answer body also for completeness.

Comment: Thanks! also, just for fun, see my new edit with a single command (using piping) version that removes nulls and double-0's.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a list like in my example, you can use `dplyr`, like this:

```
require(dplyr)
lista <- list(as.data.frame(matrix(c(0,0), nrow = 1)), 
          as.data.frame(matrix(c(37.4590,-122.1781), nrow = 1)), 
          as.data.frame(matrix(c(NA,NA), nrow = 1)), 
          as.data.frame(matrix(c(42.5153,-70.9075), nrow = 1))) # toy example
names(lista) <- 1:4 # each element in the list has a name

lista %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(V1), !is.na(V2)) %>%  # here you remove NAs
  filter(V1 != 0, V2 != 0) # here you remove zeros
```